# Eu4 How to specify province in province events?

Tags: mods, europa-universalis-iv

So I'm having trouble figuring out how to specify what provinces a province event will happen in while modding Europa. I want to make the event only occur for provinces neighboring a country other than the one the province is owned by. Will it work something like this?

```
province_event = {
    id = example
    title = example
    desc = exampledesc
    picture = DIPLOMACY_eventPicture

    trigger = {
        always = no
        any_neighbor_province = {
            limit = {
            }
        }
    }
...
```

EDIT: I fixed it

```
any_neighbor_province = {
    owned_by = controller
}
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Arqade!  I'm glad to know that you fixed your problem, but that's not how the site is supposed to work.  Rather than editing the question, please post your solution as an answer.  Or even as a comment, although that doesn't work well with code blocks.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll do that next time I have a question.

Comment: The 'always = no' is unnecessary. 'no' is the default value. Most of the time anyway. Definitely here, but there might be exceptions.